# how to write a countifs formula referring to a different tab, tab ref is static, column ref should by dynamic (indirect function) based on cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with lots of variables in columns. I want to make nice tables in a different tab (and do not want to use 100s of pivot tables). I need to check each column for specific values. In fact each column becomes a table. I am using the `countifs` function. To efficiently do that I want to refer in the tab where I make the tables to the tab where the data is stored (same file), that reference is static. For each and every table I need to refer to a different column, so that is the dynamic part. In stead of changing all formulas for each table, I prefer to have a reference to the specific column in one cell (for each table). I know I have to use the indirect function, but can't get it work.

```
=countifs(worksheet!E:E;b4)
```

where the E:E part should be dynamic

`=countifs(indirect("Worksheet!"&a4);b4)` or `countifs(indirect("Worksheet!"&a4;b4))` both do not seem to work

Comment: So what's in `A4`? The string "E:E"? Your formula should work if so.

Comment: As so often, once you try to explain it to someone else in a structured way ... you find yourself the solution. =countifs(indirect("Worksheet!"&a4);b4) is the right solution ... I myself mad a small error with the sequence of !, ", and & ... anyway problem solved